# Wrong Entry Being Displayed?

Tags: channel-entries, templates

I have a trainer directory that seemed to be displaying fine but now I have more than 1 entry it will just display the content for **trainer1** even if im on the page for **trainer2**.

So **/personal-trainer-directory/trainer3/** is displaying the content for **/personal-trainer-directory/trainer1/** even though the URL says **/personal-trainer-directory/trainer3/**

here is how i have the template file setup.  It’s a directory template file with Trainer Directory Search, Trainers Page, Gym Directory Search, Gyms Page:

```
{if segment_2 =="personal-trainer-directory" AND segment_3 ==""}
trainer search page
{if:else}
trainers page
{/if}

{if:elseif segment_2 =="gym-directory" AND segment_3 ==""}
gyms search page
{if:else}
gyms page
{/if}
```

Here is the code for **trainers page**: http://d.pr/n/OXg0 its a bit long so uploaded to droplr.

Been trying to figure this out for a couple hours and a bit stumped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are manually coding the url's, you want to remove the `dynamic='no'` parameter. This will allow either the `entry_id` or `url_title` to be used to pull the correct record. Dynamic 'no' overrides that, and requires that you tell the page, where to pull data to display a record entry.